# How can I remove trailing spaces & extra new line while spooling output?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

Trailing spaces in the spooled output rpad(' ',40)  are getting truncated.  If i remove the SET TRIMSPOOL on option the line size becomes 400 and there is a extra new line after each select query. What options i need to have the trailing spaces at the end and remove the extra new line.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET LINESIZE 400
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET PAGESIZE 0
SPOOL ${T_SPOOL}    

SELECT '0' || rpad(' ',17) || '01' || 'WBC' || rpad(' ',7) || rpad('Accounts ',26) ||     '407081' || rpad('REF',12)  || to_char(sysdate, 'DDMMYY') || rpad(' ',40)
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your lines all have the same fixed length, you can remove the TRIMSPOOL setting and change the LINESIZE setting to match the length required e.g.

```
SET LINESIZE 120
```

(120 was the figure I came up with via a quick mental tot-up, it may be incorrect).